# Byte Array being returned in XML, Extract?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

I have a byte array being returned by a rest service. The issue is that it is being encoded into XML. Is there anyway to extract the byte array from the XML without losing its represented file structure?

Or am I doomed to work with a string? If so is there any way to convert the string to the byte array so I can create the file it represents?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What language are you working in?  What is "represented file structure"?

Comment: c#. I am trying to transfer a file from a server. However, the server is returning the byte array embedded in xml. I need to create the file on the local machine

Comment: Ok, retag the post with C# then!  I can't help you with C#, but whoever can will need to understand how the byte array is encoded in the XML.  Is it base-64 encoded, or what?

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help! It is encoded in base64Binary

Answer (score 0):

To embed a byte array into an XML file, your best option is to encode the array into a string, via a hex encoder, or a base64 encoder. A hex encoder would accept an array like `{0xEF, 0x12, 0x5A}` into a string like "EF125A".  The base64 encoder will do something similar, but will produce a smaller string.

Then you would do the converse in order to read the xml file.

Depending on your language and platform, there are different ways to do the encoding and decoding.

Comment: C#. How would I "extract" the array from the xml?